# Is there any way by which we can list out all the dependencies or libraries installed in running docker container?

Tags: docker

Is there any way by which we can list out all the dependencies or libraries installed in running **docker container**?

Comment: login docker container 
`apt list --installed`

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly.

You can inspect the history of the image of a container: that will give you an idea of the various operations (RUN, COPY, ADD) done from a base image in order to build said image.

But don't forget a container can be run from an image a simple as SCRATCH (no files) + 1 executable (making only system call). No OS, no bash, no nothing except that one executable.
In that case, there is no dependencies or libraries to list.

Comment: Thanks a lot VonC for giving the direction... I could pull out some of the libraries installed which were listed in the Dockerfile but not all... I am facing one more issue... My docker image also consists of the libraries which are not listed in dockerfile.... they were committed directly into the image and not by first including in dockerfile and then creating an image using that dockerfile.... I used " apt list --installed && pip list" inside running docker container, which listed all of the libraries but also include the libraries which were automatically installed.

Comment: @SushilRaut Then try https://github.com/P3GLEG/Whaler on that base image.